# Finding indexed data-structure like `std::vector` (not array)

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, c++17, std

I am looking for a data structure which can store values with index and also can be resized like a `std::vector` (but should be indexed so I can access it easily) is there any C++ standard library implementation of my problem?

What I am looking for is an array-type DS from which I can remove elements.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. You can still use a vector. Pack your data in a struct or a std::pair and store this in a std::vector.

Comment: You mention "vector" by which I assume you mean `std::vector`? What about `std::vector` doesn't satisfy your requirements? How about `std::deque` or one of the associative containers (like `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`)?

Comment: @ArminMontigny Vector doesn't fulfil my requirements that's why I asked question.

Comment: @SahilSilare `std::vector` can store values, it is indexed, it can be resized and elements can be removed. Those are the only four "requirements" you have told us. You have to be more specific if that's not enough. And what is the *actual* problem you try to solve? *Why* do you need this container? What is it supposed to be used for?

Comment: It would help if you disambiguated between the STL and different versions of the C++ standard. Which C++ version are you using?

Comment: I'm using C++14

Comment: If this is too broad I wonder what short looks like

Comment: "too broad" means that the information provided in question is not specific enough, so there are too many ways how to interpret and answer it. It's not about length of the description. To avoid your questions being closed as "too broad", you need actually to add more text, making it clearer what your current specification is, and what precisely you are asking about. Like in this case it's not clear what is missing in vector for you, as `std::vector` supports all you asked for. (of course removing elements from vector may come with extra performance hit, but it may be also faster than deque)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) which is also indexed sequence container like `std::vector`. It provids also [std::deque::resize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/resize) member function.

However, your requirement should be much more specific to suggest `std::deque` at first place than `std::vector`

Comment: Can I remove an element at specified position in deque like if I want to remove 3rd element in the list of 7 elements?

Comment: @SahilSilare Yes, you can use the member function [std::deque::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/erase) for that. See the link for the explanation. That being said, if erasing element from the container was your intention, keep in mind that `std::vector` also has member [erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase).